# Error while trying to serialize to JSON - Ebean : lazy loading failed

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson, ebean

I'm working on a page that shows the history of an application (=> who did what at what time). So the idea is to get a list of history elements to show, put it into a JSON object and send it.

My problem is that at this line:

```
result.set("data", Json.toJson(historyList));
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed (through reference chain: components.Page["list"]->com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]->models.history.History["user"]->models.person.UserAccount["**mandantId**"])

Here are some extracts of my models:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = History.class)
@EntityConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.NONE)
public class History{
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private UserAccount user;
    ...
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EntityConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.NONE)
public class UserAccount{
    @Transient
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = History.class)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private History history;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I tried a lot of different annotation, not really knowing what I was doing, but I keep getting the same error.

Does anyone have an idea what else to do or to try?

#### Edit:

Here are also some other attribute from the `UserAccount` class:

```
@Id
@Required
protected Integer id;

@JsonIgnore
protected UUID uniqueId;

@Required
protected Integer mandantId;

@Required
protected Date createdOn;
```

Fun thing: if I add `@JsonIgnore` to the `mandantID` attribute, the error message changes to:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed (through reference chain: components.Page["list"]->com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]->models.history.History["user"]->models.person.UserAccount["**createdOn**"])

And if I then add `@JsonIgnore` to the `createdOn` attribute, I get the same error, but with the name of the next attribute instead.

Comment: Hum, are you sure that data is consistent at the database level? Looks like Ebean tried to load the related `UserAccount` but it was not present at the database, so maybe your data is "corrupted". Moreover, which version of Play and Ebean are you using?

Comment: I'm using Play 2.4.2 and Ebean 2.0.0, with PostgreSQL 9.5
The idea of corrupted data can be a good lead, since I don't have this error just after flipping the base and putting new datas but I get it after restarting activator. But if I look at the tables with pgAdmin, it doesn't tell me that they need vacuum (which should happen if the data is corrupt)

Comment: Are you sure you are using Ebean 2.0.0? I can't even find this version anymore since it is pretty old (2010, probably).

Comment: I'm afraid so. This is the line in the plugins.sbt file :
> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.0.0")

Comment: You are actually using **play-ebean** 2.0.0 which adds [Ebean 6.8.1](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/blob/2.0.0/build.sbt#L59). About data corruption, what I mean was that maybe you have inconsistent data at your database. Try to see if each `History` have their correspondent `UserAccount` row.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue and my data is consistent. I am using play 2.5 and play-ebean 3.0 which is ebean 7. I debugged and found that whenever jackson tries to serialize the data in my case  and it usages refelection to read fields that ebean tries to fire extra DB query and then EntityBeanIntercept.java class throws this error. Still not sure why ebean is doing like this. Any suggestions here ?